# Proving by contradiction that $A \subset B \implies \sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$, for $A$ and $B$ bounded subsets of $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Yesterday I saw a question related to calculus 1 in which they asked for a proof for the following:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$.
> $$A \subset B \implies \sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$$

The moment I saw it, reasoning by *reductio ad absurdum* came to my mind. So my personal proof would be:

> Let's assume that the assertion
> $$A \subset B \implies \sup(A) > \sup(B)$$
> is true and we find a contradiction: $\sup(A) > \sup(B)$, since $\sup(B)$ is the smallest upper bound of $B$ and $\sup(A)$ strictly greater than $\sup(B)$ then this means that $\sup(A)$ which can belong to set $A$ does not belong to set $B$ and this is a contradiction because $A$ is included in $B$.
>
> So we have shown by contradiction that the assertion $A \subset B \implies \sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$ is true.

Many teachers proved the same assertion with direct reasoning, but I preferred the absurd reasoning. What do you think about it? Is my proof true?

Thanks already.

Comment: A proof is not true or false $-$ it is valid or invalid (you could also say it is correct or incorrect). A _statement_ is true or false.

Comment: The proof does not work as it is because the supremum of a set needn't be an element of that set.

Comment: The fact that $\sup(A)$ can be an element of $A$ isn't enough, because your argument seems to require that it's necessarily an element of $A$. Also, the negation of $A \subset B \implies \sup(A) \le \sup(B)$ is not $A \subset B \implies \sup(A) > \sup(B)$. The assertion to be proved is implicitly universal: "for all sets $A$ and $B$, $A \subset B \implies \sup(A) \le \sup(B)$". Thus its negation is existential: "there exist sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \subset B$ and $\sup(A) > \sup(B)$" (note "and", not "$\implies"). Fortunately this highlights the fact that you only need one counterexample!

Comment: @GregMartin A single example would suffice to establish "there exist sets...", but we want to show that this statement is false. I don't know how a counterexample would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The proof isn't correct.  There's a problem with the word "can" in the phrase "sup $A$ which can belong to $A$."   "Can" is not enough.  Take a simpler example:

Prove that if $x < y$ then $x^2 < y^2$.

First note that the statement is not true.  We have $-3 < -2$ but $(-3)^2 > (-2)^2$.   But pretend we didn't notice that and we use your method of proof:

Since $x$ and $y$ can both be positive, we have $x^2 < xy < y^2$, therefore we're done.

Nope.  The statement is true in special cases, but not in all cases.  "Can" takes to special cases.   I guess your prove works in the special case that sup $A$ does belong to $A$, but what about the other cases?

Comment: I get it, that's a special case, in general we could say: because sup(A) > sup(B), then ∃ x ∈ A and x > sup (B). So in this case sup(B) < x < sup(A) x belongs to A but doesn't belong to B and this is a contradiction because A is included in B.

Comment: I think you need a bit more than that.  How do you know that $x > $ sup $B$?     Let $\epsilon = $ sup $A - $ sup $B$.  Then consider the interval of radius $\epsilon/2$ about sup $A$.  Does it contain an element of $A$?  Is it bigger than  sup $B$?

Comment: it is because sup(A) is greater than sup(B), that an x which belongs to A could be greater than sup(B) but at the same time less than sup(A).

Comment: Do you find it true this time?

Comment: @AmineNsr There is ambiguity in your language. Your phrase _"an x which belongs to A could be greater than sup(B)"_ can be understood in two different ways: (_i_) it is possible that such $x$ exists; (_ii_) it is always possible to find such $x$, in other words, such an $x$ _always_ exists. You need to figure out which one you require, (i) or (ii). Then you need to prove your claim. [I am not B. Goddard]

Comment: @paperskilltrees "an x which belongs to A could be greater than sup(B)" meant  ∃ x ∈ A such that sup(B) < x.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your argument contains some flaws. That being said, here's how I would do a (very verbose) contradiction argument: assume that $A \subset B$, where $B$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Assume, to the contrary, that $\sup A > \sup B$. Because $A \subset B$, it follows that $a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$. By definition, for every $$b \in B, b \le \sup B < \sup A,$$ by our assumption. However, this also implies that $\sup B$ is an upper bound of $A$. That is, for every $a \in A, a \le \sup B < \sup A$, and so $\sup B$ is a smaller upper bound than $\sup A$, which is impossible!